# VSTS-Agent not building cordova iOS application

Tags: ios, cordova, tfs, tfsbuild

When trying to build my cordova application i'm getting a 'undefined is not a function' when building on my OSX with the VSTS-agent (cross platform).

My build log:

```
tf resolvePath -workspace:ws_1_13 $/projectname/Source/BerichtgevingApp/Cordova/res/certificates/ios/Distribution.p12 -collection:http://mycompany17:8080/tfs/Projecten/ -jwt:******** -noprompt
/Users/mycompany/Documents/TFSAgent/vsts-agent-osx.10.11-x64-2.105.7/_work/1/s/res/certificates/ios/Distribution.p12
tf resolvePath -workspace:ws_1_13 $/projectname/Source/BerichtgevingApp/Cordova/res/certificates/ios/projectname_Berichtgeving_App.mobileprovision -collection:http://mycompany17:8080/tfs/Projecten/ -jwt:******** -noprompt
/Users/mycompany/Documents/TFSAgent/vsts-agent-osx.10.11-x64-2.105.7/_work/1/s/res/certificates/ios/projectname_Berichtgeving_App.mobileprovision
tf resolvePath -workspace:ws_1_13 $/projectname/Source/BerichtgevingApp/Cordova -collection:http://mycompany17:8080/tfs/Projecten/ -jwt:******** -noprompt
/Users/mycompany/Documents/TFSAgent/vsts-agent-osx.10.11-x64-2.105.7/_work/1/s
agent.workFolder=/Users/mycompany/Documents/TFSAgent/vsts-agent-osx.10.11-x64-2.105.7/_work
loading inputs and endpoints
loading INPUT_PLATFORM
loading INPUT_CONFIGURATION
loading INPUT_CORDOVAVERSION
loading INPUT_ANTBUILD
loading INPUT_KEYSTOREFILE
loading INPUT_IOSSIGNMETHOD
loading INPUT_P12
loading INPUT_P12PWD
loading INPUT_UNLOCKDEFAULTKEYCHAIN
loading INPUT_PROVPROFILE
loading INPUT_REMOVEPROFILE
loading INPUT_XCODEDEVELOPERDIR
loading INPUT_WINDOWSPHONEONLY
loading INPUT_WINDOWSONLY
loading INPUT_CWD
loading INPUT_OUTPUTPATTERN
loading INPUT_TARGETEMULATOR
loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_$/
loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_SCHEME_$/
loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_PARAMETER_$/_ACCESSTOKEN
loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION
loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_SCHEME_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION
loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_PARAMETER_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION_ACCESSTOKEN
loaded 23
BUILD_SOURCEDIRECTORY=undefined
BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY=/Users/mycompany/Documents/TFSAgent/vsts-agent-osx.10.11-x64-2.105.7/_work/1/s
CWD=/Users/mycompany/Documents/TFSAgent/vsts-agent-osx.10.11-x64-2.105.7/_work/1/s
XCODEDEVELOPERDIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
CONFIGURATION=Release
ARCHS=null
PLATFORM=ios
TARGETEMULATOR=false
WINDOWSAPPX=null
WINDOWSONLY=false
WINDOWSPHONEONLY=false
UNLOCKDEFAULTKEYCHAIN=false
DEFAULTKEYCHAINPASSWORD=null
P12=/Users/mycompany/Documents/TFSAgent/vsts-agent-osx.10.11-x64-2.105.7/_work/1/s/res/certificates/ios/Distribution.p12
P12PWD=password
IOSSIGNINGIDENTITY=null
PROVPROFILEUUID=null
PROVPROFILE=/Users/mycompany/Documents/TFSAgent/vsts-agent-osx.10.11-x64-2.105.7/_work/1/s/res/certificates/ios/projectname_Berichtgeving_App.mobileprovision
REMOVEPROFILE=true
ANTBUILD=false
KEYSTOREFILE=/Users/mycompany/Documents/TFSAgent/vsts-agent-osx.10.11-x64-2.105.7/_work/1/s
KEYSTOREPASS=null
KEYSTOREALIAS=null
KEYPASS=null
OUTPUTPATTERN=bin
CORDOVAARGS=null
CORDOVAVERSION=6.3.1
undefined is not a function
task result: Failed
Task failed
Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]Task failed
Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]Task failed
```

I'm using this build agent https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-cordova-tasks / https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vsclient.cordova-extension. It's an TFS 2015 Update 3 env.

Screenshot of build service:

[image: https://gyazo.com/f8d3e3628732096b0ef05f876b4f4262]

Comment: Why you got two BUILD_SOURCEDIRECTORY, one with `BUILD_SOURCEDIRECTORY=undefined ` in your log. This may cause the issue.

Comment: No idea. These are the variables im using: https://gyazo.com/2c27b2cc39c3f5bf9e8003ca9b800c84. I think they are provided by the Cordova TFS task

Comment: Can you build it successfully if you build it on the agent manually?

Comment: I can run it successfully when going to the agentname/_work/1/s/projectmap and run `cordova prepare ios` + `cordova build --release ios`. No errors their. I'm not 100% sure what the cordova tasks exactly does and which commands are being ran. Sadly enabling debug mode doesn't show the shell commands

Comment: I just created a cordova app and build it with the same settings as you, but cannot reproduce it. Can you download the latest XPlat agent version and also make sure that you are using the latest task version then try again?

Answer (score 0):

Since you can run the build via command, before you figure the issue out, you can also add "Command Line" task to run the build as a workaround.
[image]